# rspec testing getter and setter methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, getter-setter

task.rb

```
#executor (user class) has one profile and has many tasks.

def task_name_company
  [executor.try(:profile).try(:first_name), executor.try(:profile).try(:last_name), executor.try(:profile).try(:company)].join(' ')
end

def task_name_company=(name)
  self.executor = User.joins(:profile).where("CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name, company) LIKE ?", "%#{name}%").first if name.present?
rescue ArgumentError
  self.executor = nil
end
```

task_spec.rb

```
let(:task) = { create(:task) }
let(:user) = { create(:user) }
let(:profile = { create(:profile) }


# I tested the getter like this and seems to be working
it "task_name_company getter" do
  task.executor.profile = profile
  expect(task.task_name_company).to eq("John Doe ABC Inc")
end

# I don't know how to test the setter method

it "task_name_company setter" do
end
```

UPDATE FOR LET VS LET!

user.rb

```
def decrease_new_chat_notifications
  decrement!(:new_chat_notification) if self.new_chat_notification > 0
end

def decreasing_post_notification_number(post_id)
  notifications.this_post_comments(post_id).unchecked.each do |notification|
    checking_and_decreasing_notification(notification)
  end
end
```

user_spec.rb

```
let(:user) { create(:user) }
let(:post_notification) { create(:notification, notifiable_type: "Post", recipient: user, sender: sender, checked_at: nil, notifiable_id: post.id)}

it "decrease_new_chat_notifications if greater than 0" do
  user.new_chat_notification = 1
  expect{user.decrease_new_chat_notifications}.to change{user.new_chat_notification}.by(-1)
end

it "decreasing_post_notification_number" do
  expect(user).to receive(:checking_and_decreasing_notification).with(post_notification)
  user.decreasing_post_notification_number(post.id)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
describe '#task_name_company=' do
  let(:profile) { create(:profile, first_name: 'name', last_name: 'last', company: 'company') }
  let!(:user) { create(:user, profile: profile) }
  subject { create(:task) }

  it 'sets the executor' do
    subject.task_name_company = 'name last company'
    expect(subject.user).to eql user
  end
end
```

**UPDATE** to answer the `let!` vs `let`

```
describe '#task_name_company=' do
  let(:profile) { create(:profile, first_name: 'name', last_name: 'last', company: 'company') }
  let(:user) { create(:user, profile: profile) }
  subject { create(:task) }

  it 'sets the executor' do
    user # I'm explicitly calling user here
    subject.task_name_company = 'name last company'
    expect(subject.user).to eql user
  end
end
```

Comment: Ahh I tried something similar without the exclamation point. Mario, could you tell me when to use `let` and when `let!`?

Comment: The difference is that all `let!` is always evaluated, while `let` is lazily evaluated, so in the code above if you replace the `let!` with `let` then the `user` is created after the `expect(subject.user).to eql user` and your spec fails because you need the user before.

Comment: Also, see my updated answer to show the two versions

Comment: Mario, thx for the update. I asked it the wrong way. I mean I don't understand when it has to be defined before. I updated the question with 2 examples. So, why those work with `let` and why the setter only works with `let!`? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The setter could work with `let` if you explicitly call `user` before the calling that setter. When it has to be defined before? I think that it depends on your logic.

Comment: For example I'm calling an instance method in the new example on the user. As I see user has to be defined if I wanna call a method on it. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: You're not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
it "task_name_company setter" do
  expect(lambda {
    task.task_name_company = "blah"
  }).to  change{task.executor}.from(nil).to(user)
end
```

Comment: Nicholas, is this for the setter?

Comment: Yes, since you are checking that the setter actually sets the value. Your setter is `def task_name_company=(name)`, yes?

Comment: Not working :(. This method should return a user not the text.

Comment: ah, then try `user` instead of `"blah"` for the expectation? Perhaps you should investigate rspec a bit more http://rspec.info/documentation/. You need to understand exactly what you expect as output from your inputs..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work like so...

```
expect {
 subject.total_batch_jobs = 1
}
.to change(subject, :total_batch_jobs)
.by(2)
```

1) expect takes a block

2) change requires an object with a message and/or a `block { subject.total_batch_jobs }`